# How to create authorization with just a key in Blazor

Tags: blazor, authorization

**Alternative question title can be:**

How to make an authentication without the need of a username?

**Want to make it the simplest form for the authenticated users to access the restricted area, one step simpler than a user/pass and login forms, etc, just they need a string as the key.**

For example, anyone who enters "Christmas" can access to a component to view a book online or such a thing.

Didn't find any similar scenario in the internet.

I want to have and share a manually created **single secret key** (string) with a group of my trusted friends via a trusted source.
So don't want a routine mechanism for authentication and authorization.

Just an input box, which for example if they type "**Christmas**" (we can hash it and decode/encode) they will have access to the restricted component (preferrable) or page.

Not sure if I didn't use some exact related terms.

Though, it will be looked too simple from one aspect I want it to have a basic security, also prefer proved, pattern-based scenarios or normal routines with the minimum code or alterations as possible.

How to achieve this? suggestions or similar samples are also appreciated.

---

**Update**

Back, First of all thanks for the nice answer, I have some issues and simple questions regarding this, maybe they look simple or silly, not sure :D, Some times there are gaps between my development cycle, and I didn't use related features a while.

Here are the important parts now:

My **Index page** now looks like this:

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<SecretComp />
```

**SecretComp :**

```
@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
<h3>SecretComp</h3>
<p class="t1secret">
    Hey there you can see all the secrets!!!!
</p>
```

1. I tried to separate Admin role from the User role, and changed the below line like this:

`if (secret.Equals(_mySecrets.Value.User))
return "UserRole";`

And as you might saw, I have set only **Admin** to have the rights to see the component (just for example), but even **UserRole** can also view this component.

2. Second issue is that the authorization scope applies to the all the pages, how can I apply it to just a component, I used this in a sample component **SecretComp.razor** which used in the Index page? :

`@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]`

---

**Update 2**

Also tried this in my Index as well as the Component:

```
<AuthorizeView Roles="Admin">
  <Authorized>
    <h3>SecretComp</h3>
    <p>
      Hey there you can see all the secrets!!!!
    </p>
  </Authorized>

</AuthorizeView>
```

In this trial the authorized section never been shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build a custom `AuthenticationStateProvider`.  I built something very similar recently for testing some code.  This is my code.

It includes multiple secrets, for testing different roles.

A record to hold the secrets:

```cs
public record MySecrets
{
    public string Visitor { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    public string User { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    public string Admin { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
```

A simple `AuthenticationStateProvyder`:

```cs
public class VerySimpleAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    // default is an empty ClaimsPrincipal which won't authenticate
    private ClaimsPrincipal _user = new ClaimsPrincipal();

    // MySecrets injected by DI
    private IOptions<MySecrets> _mySecrets;

    public VerySimpleAuthenticationStateProvider(IOptions<MySecrets> secrets)
        => _mySecrets = secrets;

    public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        => Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_user);

    public Task<AuthenticationState> ChangeIdentityAsync(string? username, string? secret)
    {
        var role = GetRole(secret);

        // creates a claims array with the provided information
        Claim[] Claims = new[]{
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username ?? "Anonymous"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role ?? string.Empty)
        };

        // If we don't have role then create an empty ClaimsPrincipal which won't authenticate
        // If we do create a populated ClaimsPrincipal
        // Note you only actually need to provide an AuthenticationType for the user to be authenticated
        if (role == null)
            _user = new ClaimsPrincipal();
        else
            _user = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(Claims, "SecretAuthType"));

        // Get a new AuthenticationState and Notify any listeners that the state has changed
        var task = this.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        this.NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(task);
        return task;
    }

    private string? GetRole(string? secret)
    {
        secret = secret ?? string.Empty;

        if (secret.Equals(_mySecrets.Value.Admin))
            return "AdminRole";

        if (secret.Equals(_mySecrets.Value.User))
            return "AdminRole";

        if (secret.Equals(_mySecrets.Value.User))
            return "VisitorRole";

        return null;
    }
}
```

The secrets defined in `AppSettings`

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "MySecrets": {
    "Visitor": "Visitor",
    "User": "User",
    "Admin": "Admin"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

And the application configuration in `Program`:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

// Get the secrets from AppSettings
builder.Services.Configure<MySecrets>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MySecrets"));

// Override the default AuthenticationStateProvider loaded in AddAuthentication with ours
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, VerySimpleAuthenticationStateProvider>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

A SecretLogin Component:

```cs
<div class="m-2 p-2 bg-light">
    <div class="mb-2">
        <label class="form-label">What's my name today?</label>
        <input class="form-control" @bind=this.TodaysName />
    </div>
    <div class="mb-2">
        <label class="form-label">What's the Secret today?</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" @bind=this.TheSecret />
    </div>
    <div class="mb-2 text-end">
        <button class="btn btn-success" @onclick="LetMeIn">Let me in</button>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Inject] private AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider { get; set; } = default!;

    private string? TheSecret;
    private string? TodaysName;

    private Task LetMeIn()
    {
        if ( authenticationStateProvider is VerySimpleAuthenticationStateProvider verySimpleAuthenticationStateProvider)
        {
            verySimpleAuthenticationStateProvider?.ChangeIdentityAsync(TodaysName ?? "Anonymous", TheSecret);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And modifications to `App.razor` to show the `SecretLogin` if unauthorized.

```html
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <SecretLogin />
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Finally you need to define what components/routes need authorizing.  This line added to the root `_Imports.razor` applies authentication across the site:

```cs
@attribute [Authorize]
```

You can add this to any components/routes that don't need authorizing.

```cs
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it soon, it should be close to what I expect, May I back to you if there was any issue or related question to run it?

Comment: Yes, no problem.  Just add a message here.

Comment: Back, Edited the question and pointed 2 minor questions, hope you can help me, so I be able to continue in the right direction. Thanks and regards.

Comment: Where are you running `if (secret.Equals(_mySecrets.Value.User)`?

Comment: This line in your code was also pointing to "AdminRole", so I changed it to "UserRole" as you saw: if (secret.Equals(_mySecrets.Value.User))
return "UserRole";

Comment: Dude I added my project into github: https://github.com/KKacer/SimpAuth , still waiting and hopeful to get those answers. That may make it easier to check up.

Comment: You sure it's public?

Comment: Sorry that wasn't, now fixed it.

Comment: Mr Shaun fixed the repo yesterday, also created a chat room if you preferred to continue the discussion there: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250398/simpauth  , don't want anything other than the main topic, actually had only 2 minor issues which mentioned earlier, please have a look, thanks.

Comment: Hi @MrCakaShaunCurtis Im having a similar question and so far your solution is guiding me on the right path, just attempting to somehow integrate the authentication with signalR. Im curious how you learnt/knew about all this? The Microsoft documentation doesn't contain these details?

Comment: @user4779 - A lot of hours digging through (often inaccurate) articles, the MS DotNetCore source code, and a lot of experimenting!  I'm retired so I do the odd project, a lot of digging/deep learning in between, write the odd article, and share a little knowledge on here.  Authentication/Authorization is crying out for a good article or two but they aren't simple to write.