# How can I implement a Authentication, which doesn't allow to navigate through the Pages without being logged in? Blazor Webassembly

Tags: c#, authentication, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I don't know how to implement this problem.
This is my Login logic:

```
[Inject]
protected NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }

protected async Task HandleSubmit()
{
    Boolean success = await databaseclient.AuthenticateUserAsync(Email, Password);

    if (success)
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/startseite");
    } else
    {
        ErrorMessage = "Authentication failed. Please check your credentials.";
    }

}
```

I have tried several things with the AuthenticationStateProvider, but nothing really worked.

Comment: There are a couple of answers here that show how to build custom AuthenticationStateProviders. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77840940/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-log-out-a-claimsidentity-isauthenticated-be-false and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74740080/how-to-create-authorization-with-just-a-key-in-blazor

Comment: Not very sure about your application structure and how you implement your authentication mechanism. But I trust if you already integrated any kind of authentication mechanism, you can follow [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#require-authorization-for-the-entire-app) to add authorization requirement for all of your components so that only allowed anonymous components can be accessed before signing in.