# Force Blazor component to perform full post back

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor application that I'm toying around with. It's not using Identity because it authenticates against an external API.

I have completely disabled server rendering because I have an application state object, `CascadingAppState.razor` that goes off to an external API to get information about the user and populate internal state. This happens in the `OnInitializedAsync` method for `CascadingAppState`. The reason server rendering was disabled is because every time a page is requested the `CascadingAppState` component would hit the API again because the state information was null because the component was being re-rendered.

`CascadingAppState.razor`:

```
<CascadingValue Value="this">
    @ChildContent
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    public AppState ApplicationState { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if(ApplicationState == null)
        {
            // go off somehwere and call the API again to populate the the app state
        }
    }
}
```

Server pre-rendering is disabled thusly:

`App.razor`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
...
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="@(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(false))" />
</head>

<body>  
...
    <Routes @rendermode="@(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(false))" />
...
</body>

</html>
```

Everything works perfectly until I cleared my cookies and had to log in again. With the server pre-rendering disabled, I can't access the HTTP Context in order to sign the user in. The relevant login code looks like this (it's the same page currently as the template):

`Login.razor`:

```
    [CascadingParameter]
    private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;

    public async Task LoginUser()
    {
        // call 3rd party api to test user auth
        // build up a claims principal
        var claims = new List<Claim>()
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, Model.Email),
            new Claim(WebAppConstants.CLAIM_API_TOKEN, loginResponse.AccessToken.Value),
            new Claim(WebAppConstants.CLAIM_USER_ID, loginResponse.UserId)
        };
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
            new ClaimsPrincipal(identity),
            new AuthenticationProperties()
                {
                    IsPersistent = true,
                    RedirectUri = ReturnUrl ?? "/"
                });

    }
```

The `CascadingAppState` is wrapped thusly:
`Routes.razor:`

```
<CascadingAppState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" />
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
    </Router>
</CascadingAppState>
```

Is there a way to force the login page to perform a full postback in order to gain access to the HTTP Context to set the Auth cookie?

Alternatively am I doing something wrong with my application state to cause it to be re-rendered on every user interaction?

Comment: HttpContext is the context of an HTTP request in a server side API. You shouldn't be keeping an instance of it in a Blazor app. Where does it even come from?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to turn off pre-rendering to hide content that shouldn't be shown on pre-render.

You're in Global Interactivity mode, so you should only be doing a pre-render on the first page.

Here's an answer I provided a couple of months ago on how to detect the render mode and show a simple splash screen on prerender.  You should be able to adapt that to fit your needs.

[Blazor .Net 8 splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77653261/blazor-net-8-splash-screen)

### Update

If I understand this correctly you should be able to do the following:

1. Bring up a Login component in Routes if the user isn't logged in.  [you don't need the HttpContext].
2. Get the username/password [or whatever] and do the API calls to authenticate the user [I'm assuming that's what "call 3rd party api to test user auth" means].
3. Use the API response to build a Claims Principal.
4. Call a method on a custom `AuthenticationStateProvider` to refresh the Authentication State with the provided `ClaimsPrincipal`.

`CascadingAppState` can then use the CascadingAuthenticationState to get the current `ClaimsPrincipal` and get the additional data from the external provider.  You can probably refactor this into a scoped `UserService` that all components can inject.

Comment: I appreciate the time you've taken to give an answer but I'm not sure that this is going to fix my problem. I followed the instructions in the linked post - added nuget, added services and then changed my router to have a `return` if `RenderState.IsPreRender`. Using `<Routes />` and `<HeadOutlet />` in App.razor, the page never renders. If I change Routes/HeadOutlet to `@rendermode="@(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(false))"` it works, but I still have the same problem in that I can't access HttpContext from log in page when the login button is pressed.

Comment: I've just re-read your question and understand why now.  Some questions:

Comment: I've just re-read your question and understand why now. Sorry for the wrong steer, on the wrong page!  See the comments in my updated answer.  I'll provide some more detail if I'm on the right page.

Comment: Thanks for the edit I will need to play with it more this evening; if I understand correctly are you suggesting I don't log the user in to the HttpContext directly and nstead use a custom AuthenticationStateProvider? I'll take a look. The reason for the existing code was to 1) avoid identity, because it's managed by the 3rd party API and 2) ease deployment of this app so that it doesn't require a backing store. Cheers again for your time.

Comment: Yes.  There's repo of mine [here](https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo.Authorization) to demo policy based authentication.  It uses a `VerySimpleAuthenticationStateProvider` to test authorization that may provide some insights into how simple it might be.  https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo.Authorization/blob/master/Blazr.Demo.Authorization/Blazr.Demo.Authorization.Core/Auth/VerySimpleAuthenticationStateProvider.cs

Comment: And this for a login compoinent - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74740080/how-to-create-authorization-with-just-a-key-in-blazor